# Code is not working when reCaptcha input is correct

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am trying to implement Google's reCaptcha on my website's query form in php.

When the CAPTCHA is entered incorrectly, 
**I get:** "No. CAPTCHA is not entered correctly".

But when the CAPTCHA is entered correctly, 
**What I expect:** "Everything looks good" OR "CAPTCHA is correct but other values are incorrect."
**What I get:** Blank Page

Here is how I am implementing it:

```
$var1 = $_POST["var1"];
$var2 = $_POST["var2"];

require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = "<private key I got from reCaptcha>";
    $respCaptcha = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if(!$respCaptcha->is_valid) {
    echo "No. CAPTCHA is not entered correctly";

} elseif(    is_numeric($var1) 
          && preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$var2)) {        
    echo "Everything looks good";

} else {

    echo "CAPTCHA is correct but other values are incorrect.";

}
```

Please help. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the if just inside the else...

Also is this directly pasted because the line

```
'Do something...' is not commented
```

Comment: I tried changing elseif already to all its possible forms like: 'else { if(...) {} }', _no else just if statements_ cuz if CAPTCHA is incorrect, it will redirect to another page without executing further steps. But nothing works when CAPTCHA is correct and it just shows me a blank page.

Comment: what are the values of $var1,$var2 and $url when it's submitted?
must go wrong there nothing else we can see from this code

Comment: I have edited my code to make it easier to understand. I tested this code, still it is giving me a blank page. Thanks for trying.

Comment: This should work, recheck your codes. Redownload the lib from a diff source?

First put all error reporting to 1 you might have a fatal error accuring and not seeing it?